# Using mysql FULLTEXT search with hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have a table in MYSQL which uses FULLTEXT index on few columns. I am using hibernate to access MYSQL database in my web application. When I try to search on the FULLTEXT columns, using the following hibernate query:

`From posts p where MATCH (p.description) AGAINST ('testing')`

I am getting the following exception from hibernate:

`antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: AGAINST`

It seems that hibernate (version 4.3.11) does not understand the MYSQL FULLTEXT search expressions. Is there a way I can use that with hibernate? Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following options:

1. Use [native SQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#querysql)
2. Implement a custom database function for `AGAINST`.See [this](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/database-functions/) and [this](http://grails-dev.blogspot.hk/2014/10/adding-custom-operators-in-hql-for.html) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with criteria and `sqlRestriction`:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("MATCH(Themes) AGAINST (?)", theme, Hibernate.STRING));
```